# Notepad only gets 768 entries of what should be 1000 entries on a Streamwriter text file generator

Tags: c#, streamwriter, notepad

I'm making a simple program which is supposed to take an array of 1000 entries of 2 columns and put it into text format and then output it to a file.
Something kind of weird happens.  The file only receives either 950 or 768 entry rows, not 1000 as it should.  My actual array is really an array of points for use in a DrawLine kind of thing, but for the purposes of demonstrating the error, I just use a straight-up counting array.

I wonder where the problem lies.  Is it because there's a maximum size of a buffer when you add to a file?  Is it merely because there's a maximum size to a text file?  Is it because the actual file is correct but Notepad only lets me see a limited part of the file?  Should I throw out this computer and buy another?

Any help would be appreciated.  Why does it stop at 768?  That number seems arbitrary.
As you can see, it's a WindowsForm.

```
private void GcodeSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DialogResult result;  //Specifies identifiers to indicate the return value of a dialog box
        string fileName;

        using (SaveFileDialog fileChooser = new SaveFileDialog()) 
        {
            fileChooser.CheckFileExists = false;
            result = fileChooser.ShowDialog();
            fileName = fileChooser.FileName;
        }

        if(result==DialogResult.OK)
        {
            if (fileName == string.Empty)
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid File Name", "Error",
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    FileStream output = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);

                    fileWriter = new StreamWriter(output);
                    for (int t = 0; t <= 1000; t++)
                    {
                        fileWriter.WriteLine("{0}   {1}", t, t);

                    }

                    fileWriter.WriteLine("There were {0} elements in spiroArray", numberOfPoints);

                    //It only goes up to 950 in the text file.
                    //With word wrap off it goes to 764 and then it gets 1/3 way through 764 and writes 76
                }
                catch(IOException)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error opening file", "Error",
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I looked up the documentation on Streamwriter, and I really don't see anything there that says I'm limited on buffer size.  Did I miss something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `FileStream` and `StreamWriter` use buffers internally.  These will be flushed when explicitly called (via `Flush`) or when closed/disposed.

As these objects make use of external resources and implement `IDisposable` they should both be disposed.  The most common pattern for this is to use a using statement:

```
using (var stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
{
     //use writer here
}
```

Once disposed, the data in the buffers will be written to the file and the file handle will be released.

Comment: Well, that worked.  Maybe I'm missing a chunk of knowledge about C#, but what's the need for "using"?  Of course I'm using that line of code that follows "using".  Thanks, btw.  When code works, it works and understanding why is icing on the cake.

Comment: Do a bit of research - the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) is a good start.  Essentially it's a bit of syntactic sugar around `try...finally` and will ensure `Dispose` is called at the end of the scope.

Answer (score 1):

You need to close your StreamWriter.